# Can't load pyspark.ml.Pipeline model with custom transformer in spark ml pipeline because of missing positional argument for class

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks, transformer-model, mlflow

I have a custom transformer python class that I use with a spark mllib pipeline. I want to save the model and load it in another session with spark. I'm able to log the model, but I'm not able to load it after because the confidence transformer requires the labels and it is missing the positional argument. I am using pyspark==3.3.0.

```
from pyspark.ml import Transformer, PipelineModel
from pyspark.ml.param import Param, Params
from pyspark.ml.util import DefaultParamsWriter, DefaultParamsReader, MLReadable, MLWritable, MLWriter
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer
from pyspark.ml.classification import LogisticRegression


class Confidence(Transformer, DefaultParamsReadable, DefaultParamsWritable):
    """
    A custom Transformer which does some cleanup of the output of the model and creates a column a confidence metric based on a T distribution.
    """
    
    labels = Param(
        Params._dummy(),
        "labels",
        "Count of labels for degrees of freedom",
        typeConverter=TypeConverters.toInt)

    def __init__(self, labels: int):
        super(Confidence, self).__init__()
        self._setDefault(labels=labels)
        
    def getLabels(self):
        return self.getOrDefault(self.labels)

    def setLabels(self, value):
        self._set(labels=value)

    def _transform(self, df):
        return df.withColumn("labelCount", lit(self.getLabels()))
```

```
# String Indexer to convert feature column
stringIndexer = StringIndexer(inputCol = "feature", outputCol = "label").fit(train)
# Fit model
lr = LogisticRegression()
# Get count of labels from string indexer to pass to confidence
labelCount = len(stringIndexer.labels)
confidence = Confidence(labels = labelCount)

# Create pipeline and fit model
pipeline = Pipeline().setStages([stringIndexer, lr, confidence])
pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(train_df)

basePath = "/tmp/mllib-persistence-example"
pipeline_model.write().overwrite().save(basePath + "/model")
```

```
model_loaded = Pipeline.load(basePath + "/model")
```

I get this error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1923614380916072> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 model_loaded = Pipeline.load(basePath + "/model")

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in load(cls, path)
    444     def load(cls, path: str) -> RL:
    445         """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
--> 446         return cls.read().load(path)
    447 
    448 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in load(self, path)
    247             return JavaMLReader(cast(Type["JavaMLReadable[Pipeline]"], self.cls)).load(path)
    248         else:
--> 249             uid, stages = PipelineSharedReadWrite.load(metadata, self.sc, path)
    250             return Pipeline(stages=stages)._resetUid(uid)
    251 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/pipeline.py in load(metadata, sc, path)
    437                 stageUid, index, len(stageUids), stagesDir
    438             )
--> 439             stage: "PipelineStage" = DefaultParamsReader.loadParamsInstance(stagePath, sc)
    440             stages.append(stage)
    441         return (metadata["uid"], stages)

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in loadParamsInstance(path, sc)
    727             pythonClassName = metadata["class"].replace("org.apache.spark", "pyspark")
    728         py_type: Type[RL] = DefaultParamsReader.__get_class(pythonClassName)
--> 729         instance = py_type.load(path)
    730         return instance
    731 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in load(cls, path)
    444     def load(cls, path: str) -> RL:
    445         """Reads an ML instance from the input path, a shortcut of `read().load(path)`."""
--> 446         return cls.read().load(path)
    447 
    448 

/databricks/spark/python/pyspark/ml/util.py in load(self, path)
    638         metadata = DefaultParamsReader.loadMetadata(path, self.sc)
    639         py_type: Type[RL] = DefaultParamsReader.__get_class(metadata["class"])
--> 640         instance = py_type()
    641         cast("Params", instance)._resetUid(metadata["uid"])
    642         DefaultParamsReader.getAndSetParams(instance, metadata)

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'labels'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to load a fitted pipeline shouldn't it be:

`model_loaded = PipelineModel.load(basePath + "/model")`

Comment: Please use the comments function unless you have confidence that your answer is the solution to OP's problem/question.